# How do I tackle this issue in my Guess The Flag Django web app

Tags: django, django-views, django-channels, django-sessions

I'm completely new to Django and I'm trying to build this guess the flag web game with it.
 In main page when someone presses the 'play' button, he's sent to a page where a list of 4 randomly selected countries from the DB is generated, and only of one these 4 countries is the actual answer.

Here's the code from **views.py** in my App directory :

```
context = {}
context['submit'] = None
context['countries_list'] = None
score = []
score.clear()
context['score'] = 0

def play(request):

   len_score = len(score)
   countries = Country.objects.all()
   real_choice = None   

   if request.POST:
       get_guess = request.POST.get('guess')
       print(request.POST)
       
       if str(get_guess).casefold() == str(context['submit']).casefold():
           score.append(1)
       else:
           score.clear()
       len_score = len(score)
   choices = random.sample(tuple(countries),4)
   real_choice = random.choice(choices)

   context['countries_list'] = choices
   context['submit'] = real_choice
   context['score'] = len_score

   return render (request, 'base/play.html', context)
```

Everything works as expected when there's only one person playing, or the site is opened in only one tab.

The issue here is one someone else opens the site or it's opened in more than one tab, the score gets reset and a new list of random countries is generated for all users, so your guess will never be right!

How do I go about to solve this? Again, I'm completely new to this so I'm left clueless here.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to store short term, per user information is by [session variables](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/sessions/#session-object-guidelines).  This way you can maintain the user's individual settings. So, something like:

```
def play(request):

   len_score = len(score)
   countries = Country.objects.all()
   real_choice = None   

   if request.POST:
       get_guess = request.POST.get('guess')
       print(request.POST)
       
       #Compare guess to session variable 
       #(using .get() which returns none rather than error if variable not found)
       if str(get_guess).casefold() == str(request.session.get('real_choice').casefold():
           score.append(1)
       else:
           score.clear()
       len_score = len(score)
   choices = random.sample(tuple(countries),4)
   real_choice = random.choice(choices)
   #Store answer in session variable
   request.session['real_choice'] = real_choice

   context['countries_list'] = choices
   context['submit'] = real_choice
   context['score'] = len_score

   return render (request, 'base/play.html', context)
```